# Could not load file or assembly with created library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

So while I was trying to test out libraries and console apps using .Net core I wasn't able to get simple setup working. I made a library from a template with a Class that had a method which would just print to console. Then referenced and included said library. Created an object with that class and called the method. But I got this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is using VS2017 and .NET Core (The cross platform one.).

```
# App
using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LibClass c = new LibClass();
            c.Test();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}

# Lib

using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class LibClass
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, what version are you using?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Visual Studio 2017. In meantime I tried adding NuGet package or adding solution reference and both of those worked. Only direct DLL reference doesn't work.